# How to add a condition in Struts iterator tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl

I want to highlight a row when the value of rating is less than or equal to `2`. I am not able to use the `<s:if>` to get my result. Please tell me how to put condition in my JSP page.

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="fb" status="abc">
<s:if test="#abc.rating==2">
<td style="background: #CCCCCC">
</s:if>

<tr>
<td><s:property value="cid"/></td>
<td><s:property value="cname"/></td>
<td><s:property value="rating"/></td>
<td><s:property value="likes"/></td>
<td><s:property value="dislikes"/></td>
<td><s:property value="suggestion"/></td>
</tr>

</s:iterator>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `rating` is a property of the object being iterated. Then inside the iterator tag you can access it by property name.

```
<s:if test="rating==2">
 <s:set var="myStyle" value="'background: #CCCCCC'"/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
 <s:set var="myStyle" value="'background: #FFFFFF'"/> 
</s:else>
```

then use HTML `style` attribute

```
<td style="<s:property value='#myStyle'/>">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

1. property name:

   ```
   <s:iterator value="mySource">
       <s:if test="rating==2">
   ```
2. `var` alias reference:

   ```
   <s:iterator value="mySource" var="myVar">
       <s:if test="#myVar.rating==2">
   ```
3. IteratorStatus index:

   ```
   <s:iterator value="mySource" status="myStat">
       <s:if test="mySource[%{#myStat.index}].rating==2">
   ```
4. `top` reference:

   ```
   <s:iterator value="mySource">
       <s:if test="top.rating==2">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EL (expression language) like this

```
<td style="background: ${abc.rating<=2 ? '#CCCCCC' : ''}">
```

or you can define bean variable

```
<logic:lessEqual value="2" name="abc" property="rating">
  <bean:define id="colorTd" value="#CCCCCC"/>
</logic:lessEqual>

<td style="background: ${colorTd}">
```

Comment: This is Struts 1, question is about Struts 2, unless you're using some very odd tag prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use test="%{abc.rating==2}" like this instead of test="#abc.rating==2"

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="fb" status="abc">
<s:if test="%{abc.rating==2}">
<td style="background: #CCCCCC">
</s:if>

<tr>
<td><s:property value="cid"/></td>
<td><s:property value="cname"/></td>
<td><s:property value="rating"/></td>
<td><s:property value="likes"/></td>
<td><s:property value="dislikes"/></td>
<td><s:property value="suggestion"/></td>
</tr>

</s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: No. There is no need for `%{}` in `test` attribute of `<s:if>` tag.